# Facebook notification with Wizcorp Facebook plugin for phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I am using Wizcorp Facebook plugin for phonegap. I need to send user notification to the app user. but have no idea on how to do it and i couldn't able to find docs on it.

```
 FB.api('/'+from+'/notifications', 
       'post', 
       {
           access_token: "{{ Config::get('facebook.appId') }}|{{ Config::get('facebook.secret') }}",
           template: vname + " requests you to connect with " + tname       
       });
```

This is how I was using it in Javascript SDK.

I couldn't find a structure for the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Wizcorp Facebook Plugin they have a method called `.api(String requestPath, Array permissions, Function success, Function failure)` which allows you to make requests on the Graph. The Wizcorp guide on GitHub has some [great documentation](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

Please not however, that creating user notifications requires an app access token, not a user access token, and is only applicable to Canvas Apps